# jqueryUI Datepicker plus Validator in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui

I have a form with a jQuery UI Datepicker, which then gets validated using the jQuery Validation plugin.

Datepickers are created using:

```
$("#dob").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (){
            this.focus();   
        },
    });
```

However the validation plugin seems to validate in the US format when I require it to validate using dd/mm/yyyy. This means that any date past the 12th of any month is deemed invalid.

I have looked around and I found a method to add a different way to validate the date using a regular expression:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "australianDate",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/((19|20)\\d\\d)$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy."
);
```

which is then added to the rules:

```
        dob:{
             required:true,
             australianDate: true
        },
```

but this still seems to fail for any input.

the regular expression I am using is one I have used in the past with php and is a bit more accurate then the generic (any2numbers/any2numbers/any4numbers) expression, and I would like to be able to use it in the javascript aswell.

Do javascript regular expressions need to be in a different format to php? is that where I am going wrong..

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure that `\\d\\d` should be `\d\d`. But there are better ways of validating a date.

Comment: Oh, and you should use `test`, not `match`, e.g. `/^...$/.test(value)` as it explicitly returns a boolean.

Comment: The answer by RobG does the trick without any libs or regex AND also validates the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a comment:

A better date validation function is:

```
// Expects date string in format dd/mm/yyyy
function isValidDate(s) {
  if (s === null || s.length !== 10) {
    return false;
  }
  s = s.split('/');
  var d = new Date(s[2], --s[1], s[0]);
  return d.getFullYear() == s[2] && d.getDate() == s[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```

Try the above pattern i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. While both answers did work, they did not validate things like leap years or Feb must be max 28/29..

I kept looking around and managed to find another jquery plugin simply called [date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/).

once linked you simply have to call the `Date.parseExact` function:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("australianDate", function(value, element) { 
    return Date.parseExact(value, "d/M/yyyy");
}, "Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy.");
```

Validates leap years and everything else I have tested correctly.